# Problems simply uploading a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a form where the user can upload a file:  `:File` is a column in my `Setting model`

```
<%= form_for(@setting) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Patientendaten' %>
    <%= f.file_field :file %>
  </div>
.......
```

There is no problem when I don't upload a file and just edit other "settings". But when I try to upload a file I get this error:

```
 NoMethodError in SettingsController#update
  undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

  app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:72:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:71:in `update'
```

The corresponding params are:

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"eFchgMpE0A46jQI0asmiR2wH+4kq/vmSzDchlBmMJaA=",
 "setting"=>{"adobe"=>"",
 "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x3764b98 @original_filename="prawn.rb",
 @content_type="application/octet-stream",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"setting[file]\";              filename=\"prawn.rb\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/STADLE~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20130919-6776-   1bs1n2d>>,
 "treiber"=>"",
 "port"=>"",
 "druckername"=>"",
 "bild"=>"C:/geburtstag/app/vorderseite/default.jpg",
 "anrede"=>"",
 "text"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Speichern",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

I suppose that the error occurs because of the params?

If you want to see my controller:

```
def update
@setting = Setting.find(params[:id])


respond_to do |format|
  if @setting.update_attributes(params[:setting])

    pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size=> "A4",:margin => 0)
    pdf.image @setting.bild ,:at  => [0, Prawn::Document::PageGeometry::SIZES["A4"][1]],:fit => Prawn::Document::PageGeometry::SIZES["A4"]
    Dir.chdir  Rails.root.to_s + '/vorderseite' do |dir|
    pdf.render_file "vorderseite.pdf"
    end


    format.html { redirect_to patients_path, notice: 'Setting was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @setting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Model:

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :anrede, :text, :adobe , :bild, :treiber, :port, :druckername, :file
  before_save :default_values
   def default_values 
   self.bild = Rails.root.to_s + '/vorderseite/default.jpg' if self.bild.blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you redact controller code ? Because from what stacktrace say, `def update` is on line 71, and error occurs on line 72. ... which, would but the simple `#find` instruction. If it's not edited, did you overide `#find` in your Setting model ?

Comment: Thanks, can you be more specific? I dont really get whats wrong? or should i post my settings model?

Comment: I would like you confirm line 72 is indeed `@setting = Setting.find(params[:id])`, because this line seems perfectly legit and stack trace complains about it.

Comment: No sorry line 72 is  if @setting.update_attributes(params[:setting])

Comment: Ok, so it happens in `#update_attributes`. First, can you provide proper params content ? Because in the params dump you posted, "commit" and "id" are within "setting" key, which is probably not the case. Second, are the lines from stacktrace you posted the top level ones ? I think your problem may be a model callback, but it would appear in stack trace.

Comment: So now i updated my params and added my model! I really want to say thank you !

Comment: I also want to say that the error only appears when i select an file for the file_field! When i only edit the other inputs i get no error!

Comment: Maybe the problem is that in the params `name=\"setting[file]\"`

Comment: Almost there :) I think the problem is your `attr_accessible` containing `:file`, while it's probably not a database attribute. So, as a last step, can you show your database schemas for this table ?

Comment: `file:string` is in my setting database!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you manage upload : you can't just pass what an `input[type="file"]` produces to the database, especially a fields of type String : when you upload a file, it's only provided as temporary file, you have to persist it somewhere, and make database remember its path.

You can [see what rails guides has to say about how to handle uploads](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#what-gets-uploaded). With the recommanded method, you would remove the "file" attribute from your model (and attr_accessible), take the IO generated by upload in `params` in your controller, write its content somewhere in the filesystem and then save the filepath (probably in the `bild` attribute).

But that may be time consuming and it's prone to security problems (you have to take special care to prevent someone uploading a file named `../../../../../../../../etc/passwords` which would override your server password files, for example).

In real case scenario, we often use third party libs to handle uploads, like [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave).

With Paperclip, for example, you would add something like that in your model :

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :anrede, :text, :adobe , :bild, :treiber, :port, :druckername

 has_attached_file :bild
end
```

(provided your upload field is `bild`).

This will let you do exactly what you currently do :

```
@setting.update_attribute( params[ :setting ] )
```

See paperclip documentation for more details.

Edit : added more info on temporary file in first paragraph

Comment: Thanks the answer really is perfectly! You helped me a lot!. I would give you extra points if you can say me, how i can wirte something like that `.update_attributes(params[:setting]) except param[:setting][:file]` The thing is i only need to upload an file to parse it! After that it can be deleted

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to save all attributes from params[:setting] but `:file` ? Well, you could go something like `file = params[:setting].delete(:file); @setting.update_attributes(params[:setting])`, which would remove `:file` from the hash and store it in the `file` variable. But the best you could do would probably not to put it in `:setting` in first place :) To do that, use [field_field_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-file_field_tag) instead of `f.file_field`.

Comment: But then, your form builder is not aware anymore it should be multipart, so do not forget to add the multipart option on `form_for`

Answer (score 0):

You should use multipart form to upload files:-

```
form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f...
```

Comment: This is not needed with `#form_for`, only with `#form_tag`. `#form_for` use a form builder which know when to create a multipart tag (ie: when its `#file_field` method is called)